# Decomposition of identity

Tags: co.combinatorics

Fix an integer $n$ and consider a finite numbers $m$ of subsets $ S_i  \subset [n]$ such that $$ \bigcup_{i = 1}^m S_i = [n].$$ Do we have a necessary and sufficient condition on the subsets $S_i$ so that there exists $c_i > 0$ satisfying $$ \sum_i c_i \chi_{S_i} = \chi_{[n]} ?$$ Here $[n] = \{1,\dots,n\}$ and $\chi_S$ is the indicator function of the set $S$.

Comment: Which kind of condition do you look for? Say, certain type of Hahn-Banach gives such a condition.

Comment: @FedorPetrov, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1214867), how would you use Hahn–Banach here?

Comment: If $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is an assignment of signed weights to $[n]$, write $W(A)=\sum_{j\in A}w_j$. A necessary and sufficient condition (although not one that seems to be in the form the OP is requesting) is that for every assignment of weights such that $W(S_i)\ge 0$ for each $i$, we have $W([n])\ge 0$. I believe this is the dual (in the optimization sense) to the given problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\J{\mathcal J}\newcommand\J{\mathcal J}\newcommand\B{\mathcal B}\newcommand{\cupdot}{\mathbin{\mathaccent\cdot\bigcup}}$Instead of the set $[m]$, let us use any set $M$ of a finite cardinality $m:=|M|$. Also, let us write $1_A$ instead of $\chi_A$, assuming that the indicators of the form $1_A$ are defined on the set $[n]$, so that $1_A(x)=1(x\in A)$ for $A\subseteq[n]$ and $x\in[n]$.

Introduce the following notations/definitions:

- $\J$ will denote the set of all nonempty subsets of $M$.
- $J,J_1,J_2,\dots,K$ will stand for arbitrary elements of the set $\J$.
- for any family $(c_i)_{i\in M}$ of real numbers,
  \begin{equation*}
      c_J:=\sum_{i\in J}c_i. \tag{1}\label{1}
  \end{equation*}
- $$S_J:=\bigcap_{i\in J}S_i\cap\bigcap_{i\in J^c}S_i^c,$$
  where $S_i^c:=[n]\setminus S_i$ and $J^c:= M\setminus J$ for $J\in\J$.
- Let us say that $J$ is bad if $S_J\ne\emptyset$. Let $\B$ denote the set of all bad sets $J$.

> **Theorem:** For the desired equality
> \begin{equation*}
>     \sum_{i\in M}c_i\,1_{S_i}=1 \tag{2}\label{2}
> \end{equation*}
> to hold for some strictly positive $c_i$'s, it is necessary that $\B$ be an [antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20in%20the%20area,is%20known%20as%20its%20width.) wrt the $\subseteq$ ordering.
> Also, for \eqref{2} to hold for some nonnegative $c_i$'s, it is sufficient that $\B$ be an [antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20in%20the%20area,is%20known%20as%20its%20width.) wrt the $\subseteq$ ordering.

*Proof:*
Note that
the set $[n]$ is the disjoint union of the $S_J$'s over all $J\in\J$:
\begin{equation*}
    \bigsqcup_{J\in\J}S_J=[n] \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation*}
and, for each $i\in M$,
\begin{equation*}
    S_i=\bigsqcup_{J\in\J,\,J\ni i}S_J.
\end{equation*}
So, in view of \eqref{1},
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i\in M}c_i\,1_{S_i}=\sum_{J\in\J}c_J\,1_{S_J}. \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{equation*}

To obtain a contradiction, suppose that $\B$ is not an antichain while \eqref{2} holds for some strictly positive $c_i$'s. Then for some $J$ and $K$ in $\B$ we have $S_J\ne\emptyset$, $S_K\ne\emptyset$, $J\subsetneq K$, and hence, in view of \eqref{1}, $c_J<c_K$. On the other hand, by \eqref{2} and \eqref{4}, for each $L\in\J$
\begin{equation*}
    1=\sum_{i\in M}c_i\,1_{S_i}
    =\sum_{I\in\J}c_I\,1_{S_I}=c_L \text{ on }S_L, 
\end{equation*}
since the $S_I$'s are disjoint. So, the constant value $1$ of $\sum_{i\in M}c_i\,1_{S_i}$ coincides with $c_J$ on the nonempty set $S_J$ and with $c_K$ on the nonempty set $S_K$, so that $1=c_J<c_K=1$, the desired contradiction.

This proves the necessity of $\B$ being an antichain (in order for \eqref{2} to hold for some strictly positive $c_i$'s).

Let us now show that
$\B$ being an antichain is also sufficient for \eqref{2} to hold for nonnegative $c_i$'s.
This will be done by induction on $m=|M|$. The case $m=1$ is trivial. Suppose now that $m\ge2$.

Introduce
\begin{equation*}
    T_J:=\{K\colon K\subsetneq J\}\cup\{K\colon K\supsetneq J\}
    =\bigcap_{i\in J}S_i\cup\bigcap_{i\in J^c}S_i^c. 
\end{equation*}
Since $\B$ is an antichain, we have
\begin{equation*}
    T_J=S_J. 
\end{equation*}
So, if $J$ and $K$ are distinct bad sets, then $T_J\cap T_K=S_J\cap S_K=\emptyset$, and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \emptyset=\bigcap_{i\in J^c}S_i^c\cap \bigcap_{i\in K^c}S_i^c
    =\Big(\bigcup_{i\in(J\cap K)^c}S_i\Big)^c,
\end{equation*}
that is,
\begin{equation*}
    \bigcup_{i\in(J\cap K)^c}S_i=[n].
\end{equation*}
So, if $J\cap K\ne\emptyset$, then we can replace the finite index set $M$ by its proper subset $(J\cap K)^c$ and use the induction on $m=|M|$.

So, without loss of generality (wlog) all the bad sets $J$ are pairwise disjoint. Moreover, by \eqref{3},
\begin{equation*}
    [n]=\bigsqcup_{J\in\J}S_J=\bigsqcup_{J\in\B}S_J. \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{equation*}
Now, for each $J\in\B$, pick any $i_J\in J$. Then the $i_J$'s are (pairwise) distinct, since the bad sets $J$ are pairwise disjoint. Let now
\begin{equation}
    c_i:=\sum_{K\in\B}1(i=i_K). \tag{6}\label{6}
\end{equation}
Then, by \eqref{4}, \eqref{1}, \eqref{6}, the disjointness of bad sets, and \eqref{5},
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{i\in M}c_i\,1_{S_i}
    &=\sum_{J\in\J}c_J\,1_{S_J} \\ 
    &=\sum_{J\in\B}1_{S_J} \sum_{i\in J} c_i \\ 
    &=\sum_{J\in\B}1_{S_J} \sum_{i\in J} \sum_{K\in\B}1(i=i_K) \\ 
    &=\sum_{J\in\B}1_{S_J} \sum_{K\in\B} \sum_{i\in J} 1(i=i_K) \\ 
    &=\sum_{J\in\B}1_{S_J} \sum_{K\in\B} 1(J=K) \\ 
    &=\sum_{J\in\B}1_{S_J} =1, 
\end{align*}
so that \eqref{2} holds. $\quad\Box$

---

*Remark:* There is a strict-nonstrict positivity gap between the necessary and sufficient conditions in the above theorem. An obvious necessary condition
for \eqref{2} to hold for some strictly positive $c_i$'s is that for each $i\in M$ the set $S_i$ be in the smallest algebra of sets containing the set $\{S_j\colon j\in M\setminus\{i\}\}$. I suspect that this condition is also sufficient, but have been unable to prove this so far.

Comment: Hi Iosif ! Thanks a lot for your answer :O
Just about your final remark, I think part of the problem is to asign strictly positive c_i > 0 to every set S_i 
For example on {1,2,3}, if you take subsets {1,2}, {3} and {1}, you cannot find a solution.

Comment: @Anthony : There is a indeed a gap between the strict positivity and the nonnegativity here. For now, I have made a quick fix to make this explicit, but will think about how to erase this gap.

Comment: @Anthony : See also the remark added at the end of the answer.

Comment: Hi Iosif ! Yes indeed, the non-neg case is already interesting though, thx :-)